# Which is better approach to implement Viterbi algorithm in c?

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, viterbi

I want to implement the Viterbi algorithm for decoding convolutional codes.
[image: the algorithm is available here]

Would it be better to implement it using 2D arrays or using linked lists in C programming language.

I am a newbie in C and would appreciate any help regarding which method would be better with the specific reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It's be better to implement it using 2D array since you have to a*ccess random index* with a constant time complexity of **O(1)**.
You can't *access random index* in linked lists with a constant time complexity of **O(1)**.

Comment: Wrong. You don’t need to access random indices in the Viterbi algorithm. You calculate step n+1 from step n in the trellis, then walk backwards in the end to find out the Viterbi path (most likely path).

Comment: Yes you can calculate n+1 step from step n then how can you access index of Weight and PreviousState without iterate for linked list ?

Comment: Of course, each _step_ in the trellis should be represented as a fixed-length array, but the trellis itself can be a linked list of such arrays. Of course in practice you would need a very long list to offset the performance penalty of allocations and pointer-chasing, but theoretically a linked list is perfectly valid.

Comment: @TamásZahola What all would be the specific advantages of linked lists? Sorry, I am not very proficient with programming that is why I am requesting a more detailed answer.

Comment: @mathamity  Since you are new to C (or C++) I suggest you start with the simplest. Which is the array-version, IMHO. Maybe you could plug in the linked lists later.

Comment: @mathamity: linked lists have O(1) insertion (discounting allocation cost!). Arrays either have fixed size, or can be reallocated on-demand in which case they can achieve O(1) insertion *amortized*. Linked lists are not cache-friendly due to pointer-chasing, while arrays are contiguous so they’re cache friendly. If you know your code length beforehand, then use an array.